# Get result from two tables of postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables,

1) USER

```
id fullname email 
1   abc      a@a.com
2   def      b@b.com
```

2) SKILLS

```
id  user_id skills 
1   1       writer
2   1       blogger
3   2       singer
```

I want to get result like bellow,

```
fullname    email       skills
abc       a@a.com    writer,blogger
```

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Yes, tried with many different queries but I have not much experience in sql so being confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_agg() function in query to get the results.

```
Select fullname, email, array_agg(skills) from user left join skills on user.id = skills.user_id group by (fullname, email)
```

Comment: thanks for reply. when i run query i am getting bellow error, "column user.fullname must appear in group by clause or be used in aggregage function"

Comment: Yes you have to add all the columns apart from array_agg in group by clause

Comment: I solved the issue by using bellow query,SELECT  string_agg(skills,',') FROM users LEFT JOIN skills ON users.id = skills.user_id GROUP BY (fullname, email)

Comment: Great,
String_agg and array_agg are two different functions with similar kind of functionality.
Please do not forgot to upvote :P

Comment: Yes, I upvote and mark as accepted answer but i think you will have to edit the query based on group by close by adding array_agg functions.